# Why can you not access the Content-Type in a Azure API Management policy?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

As part of the inbound request I want to assess which format the data has been posted in as so I can convert from one to another. Using  I am trying to get the content type;

```
string contentType = context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Content-Type", "text/plain");
```

I was getting the default value (text/plain) no matter what I set the Content-Type in the request. I recorded the headers to see what was being set and it appears that the inbound policy does get the Content-Type header. Weird that you can set but not retrieve it.

How do I determine what format I have been sent?

Comment: try `context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Content-Type");`

Comment: What tool are you using to make a call and/or log request? I've just tried your expression and it's working fine for me.

Comment: @VitaliyKurokhtin POSTMAN and the API portal.

Comment: Used same tools to make it work. Could you share the entire policy? Are there any other statements, on other levels possibly? You could try to confirm with Fiddler that the headers you're interested in are actually sent.

Answer (score 0):

It's working with your provided code:

Content-Type: `application\json`
[image]
The complete policy:

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-body template="none">@{
           string contentType = context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Content-Type", "text/plain");
           return contentType;
        }</set-body>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```